# How to create pod using docker image from Artifactory

Tags: docker, kubernetes, artifactory, kubernetes-pod

I have created one docker image and publish that image to Jfrog Artifactory.
Now, I am trying to create kubernetes Pod or trying to create deployment using that image.

Find the content of pod.yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
   name: <name of pod>
spec:
   nodeSelector:
      type: "<name of node>"
   containers:
      - name: <name of container>
        image: <name and path of image>
        imagePullPolicy: Always
```

But I am getting **ErrImagePull** status after pod creation. That means pod is not getting created succesfully.
Error: error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried googling for ImagePullBackOff? What problems did you encountered during that process?

Comment: Please find the complete describe error message: Failed to pull image "<name of image>": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "<name of image>": failed to resolve reference "<name of image>": failed to do request: Head "<path to image/name of image>t": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
  Warning  Failed     19m (x4 over 21m)   kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed     19m (x6 over 21m)   kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   BackOff    75s (x88 over 21m)  kubelet            Back-off pulling image

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you work with private registry so you need to supply imagePullSecrets with the credentials to pull the image.

Comment: I tried using imagePullSecrets. Still getting same problem.

Comment: I am able create docker container using the same image. But not the pod.

Answer (score 1):

Please assure that you're creating the secret kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson under the same namespace.